# Change Authors' Format

Tags: titles, author

There are two things I would like to ask. The first question is how can I change 'and' in using multiple authors? Since I am using another language, i.e., Indonesia, I'd like to change 'and' with 'dan'. So, I want it to be

> Author 1, Author 2, dan Author 3

instead of

> Author 1, Author 2, and Author 3

Then, the second question is how can I add my professor's name in the title page? I want my title page to be like the following:

> Title \lineskip
> Author 1, Author 2, and Author 3 \lineskip
> Professor 1 and Professor 2 \lineskip
> Affiliation

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If possible can you make a `MWE` of your requirement? Else, should confirm what `class file` you are using